# Update from .ADP to .ACCDB without import linking tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I am attempting to update the file type for my database. My idea is to:

1. Create a blank .ACCDB database in Access 2010.
2. External Data tab -> Access -> import the ADP file.

Everyone recommends deleting the imported tables and import linking the tables from the SQL server instead.

However, because of the way my VBA is written, I'd rather avoid this at all costs.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Then import the tables. That's up to you. But you can't avoid some rewriting; a local Access database is quite different from an ADP.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it easier to read. Please review my changes and see if they work for you.